# Is a good practice to extend a Room Entity and use the same DAO and Repository?

Tags: android, android-room, android-rom, room

I wanna create two entities with the same ***fields*** and I saw that I can extend a entity to inherits fields, I'd like to know if it's a good practice to do it and if is there any problem to use one single DAO and Repository to these entities.

***Entity that I want to reuse***

```
@Entity
public class LoggedUsers {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

***New entity with same fields***

```
@Entity
public class HistoryUsers extends LoggedUsers  {

        //Same fields of the other entity

}
```

Comment: For this case, it is not a good idea. You should make a relationship between them instead.

Comment: I'm a begginer with that, could you tell me how to do it or somewhere to check ?

Comment: You can find a good example here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships

Comment: Thank you Dude! So.... just to clarify, let's say if I create a class called ' UserName ' with the field names declared and inside the entity I put ' @Embedded public UserName userName; ', I'll have both entities with the same field names, right ?

Comment: Yes, it adds those columns to the entity you're embedding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MergimRama said, it's not a good idea. Use embedded objects.

With embedded objects, I should create a class with fields that I want to use:

```
public class UserName {

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

}
```

And reuse the class with the fields in my entities, like that :

```
@Entity
public class LoggedUsers {

    @PrimaryKey public int id;

    @Embedded public UserName username;    //Here goes the fields

}

@Entity
public class HistoryUsers {

    @PrimaryKey public int id;

    @Embedded public UserName username;    //Here goes the fields

}
```